# Extracting, Formatting, and Exporting Mathematica AstronomicalData - Is There an Easier Way?

Tags: export, import, formatting, curated-data, astronomy

If any of you have tried to use Mathematica AstronomicalData and its newest replacements like StarData, you may already be familiar with the large data issues, and the almost impossible download times.
Below is the steps I use to extract, format, and export different categories of AstronomicalData. Surely, there has to be an easier way?
How can I simplify the process? Idea's welcomed. Thanks!

```
SetDirectory[$UserDocumentsDirectory]

sunMass = AstronomicalData["Sun", "Mass"];
sunLuminosity = AstronomicalData["Sun", "Luminosity"];
sunTemperature = AstronomicalData["Sun", "EffectiveTemperature"];


Length[AstronomicalData["ClassBStar"]]

dataClassBStar1 = Take[AstronomicalData["ClassBStar"], {1, 2000}];
dataClassBStar2 = Take[AstronomicalData["ClassBStar"], {2001, 4000}];
dataClassBStar3 = Take[AstronomicalData["ClassBStar"], {4001, 6000}];
dataClassBStar4 = Take[AstronomicalData["ClassBStar"], {6001, 8541}];



 listClassBStar1 = DeleteCases[
   {AstronomicalData[#, "Name"], AstronomicalData[#, "HDNumber"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "SpectralClass"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "BVColorIndex"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "EffectiveTemperature"]/sunTemperature, 
      AstronomicalData[#, "Mass"]/sunMass, 
      AstronomicalData[#, "Luminosity"]/sunLuminosity, 
      AstronomicalData[#, "AbsoluteMagnitude"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "ApparentMagnitude"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "RightAscension"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "Declination"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "ConstellationName"]}
     & /@ dataClassBStar1,
   _?(Internal`LiterallyOccurringQ[#, "NotAvailable"] &)];


listClassBStar2 = DeleteCases[
   {AstronomicalData[#, "Name"], AstronomicalData[#, "HDNumber"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "SpectralClass"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "BVColorIndex"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "EffectiveTemperature"]/sunTemperature, 
      AstronomicalData[#, "Mass"]/sunMass, 
      AstronomicalData[#, "Luminosity"]/sunLuminosity, 
      AstronomicalData[#, "AbsoluteMagnitude"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "ApparentMagnitude"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "RightAscension"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "Declination"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "ConstellationName"]}
     & /@ dataClassBStar2,
   _?(Internal`LiterallyOccurringQ[#, "NotAvailable"] &)];


listClassBStar3 = DeleteCases[
   {AstronomicalData[#, "Name"], AstronomicalData[#, "HDNumber"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "SpectralClass"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "BVColorIndex"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "EffectiveTemperature"]/sunTemperature, 
      AstronomicalData[#, "Mass"]/sunMass, 
      AstronomicalData[#, "Luminosity"]/sunLuminosity, 
      AstronomicalData[#, "AbsoluteMagnitude"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "ApparentMagnitude"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "RightAscension"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "Declination"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "ConstellationName"]}
     & /@ dataClassBStar3,
   _?(Internal`LiterallyOccurringQ[#, "NotAvailable"] &)];


listClassBStar4 = DeleteCases[
   {AstronomicalData[#, "Name"], AstronomicalData[#, "HDNumber"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "SpectralClass"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "BVColorIndex"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "EffectiveTemperature"]/sunTemperature, 
      AstronomicalData[#, "Mass"]/sunMass, 
      AstronomicalData[#, "Luminosity"]/sunLuminosity, 
      AstronomicalData[#, "AbsoluteMagnitude"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "ApparentMagnitude"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "RightAscension"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "Declination"], 
      AstronomicalData[#, "ConstellationName"]}
     & /@ dataClassBStar4,
   _?(Internal`LiterallyOccurringQ[#, "NotAvailable"] &)];


 listClassBStar = Join[listClassBStar1, listClassBStar2, listClassBStar3, 
   listClassBStar4];

Length[listClassBStar]

tableClassBStar = 
  Prepend[listClassBStar, {"Name", "HDNumber", "SpectralClass", 
    "BVColorIndex", "EffectiveTemperature", "Mass", "Luminosity", 
    "AbsoluteMagnitude", "ApparentMagnitude", "RightAscension", 
    "Declination", "ConstellationName"}];

SetDirectory[$UserDocumentsDirectory]

Export["exportClassBStar.csv", tableClassBStar1, "CSV"]
```

Then using a selected category of AstronomicalData in plots and graphs, is as easy as importing it from your local hard drive:

```
importClassAStar = 
  Import["exportClassAStar.csv", {"Data", {All}}, 
   "HeaderLines" -> 1];
importClassBStar = 
  Import["exportClassBStar.csv", {"Data", {All}}, 
   "HeaderLines" -> 1];
importClassFStar = 
  Import["exportClassFStar.csv", {"Data", {All}}, 
   "HeaderLines" -> 1];
importClassGStar = 
  Import["exportClassGStar.csv", {"Data", {All}}, 
   "HeaderLines" -> 1];
importClassMStar = 
  Import["exportClassMStar.csv", {"Data", {All}}, 
   "HeaderLines" -> 1];
importClassOStar = 
  Import["exportClassOStar.csv", {"Data", {All}}, "HeaderLines" -> 1];

importSubgiant = 
  Import["exportSubgiant.csv", {"Data", {All}}, "HeaderLines" -> 1];
importNormalGiant = 
  Import["exportNormalGiant.csv", {"Data", {All}}, "HeaderLines" -> 1];
importSupergiant = 
  Import["exportSupergiant.csv", {"Data", {All}}, "HeaderLines" -> 1];

importVariableStar = 
  Import["exportVariableStar.csv", {"Data", {All}}, 
   "HeaderLines" -> 1];


unionGiants = 
  Union[importSubgiant, importNormalGiant, importSupergiant];
```

After you follow the above process for every category of star AstronomicalData.

But the process is long and tedious.

Surely there is an easier way???

Comment: This is maybe quicker? `StarData[
 EntityClass["Star", "ClassBStar"],
 {"SpectralClass", "BVColorIndex", "EffectiveTemperature", "Mass", 
  "Luminosity", "AbsoluteMagnitude", "ApparentMagnitude", 
  "RightAscension", "Declination", "Constellation"},
 "Dataset"
 ]`  (still running here).  [I've struggling with this myself.](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/881746)

Comment: Don't know how different this is from @Szabolcs answer, but `mystardata = 
  EntityValue[
   EntityClass["Star", "ClassBStar"], {"Name", "HDNumber", 
    "SpectralClass", "BVColorIndex", "EffectiveTemperature", "Mass", 
    "Luminosity", "AbsoluteMagnitude", "ApparentMagnitude", 
    "RightAscension", "Declination", "Constellation"}, 
   "EntityAssociation"];` is speedier than the OP code.  And if you can, use an `Association` instead of a `Dataset` (just an opinion)

Comment: @JasonB Did you time it?  Mine is still running ...

Comment: Worked with StarData as well, but it feels like the EntityClass structure has serious network(?) performance issues. I can do large extracts of AstronomicalData that never return using StarData. Since the newer data like StarData, GalaxyData, etc uses EntityClass, I will have to figure out the best approach. Haven't used the "Dataset" option on StarData before. Will check into that. Thanks!

Comment: @Szabolcs - so our two methods seem the same, same timing and result (aside from the `Dataset` versus `Association`).  It *seems* like the holdup is with `"RightAscension"` - if you comment out all the other properties but that one it still takes a long time.  But you can see the progress bar move so you know it's happening.

Comment: OK, I went for a walk because I couldn't wait for it to finish.  It took 39 minutes.  The result dataset is 39 MB.  Exporting to WDX (the format used by many of these *Data functions) I get 1 MB.  My usual download speed is about 1 MB/s.  Why couldn't this be downloaded in just a couple of seconds instead of 40 minutes then?!

Comment: @JasonB Did you time yours?

Comment: That's why I used Take with 2000 increments when downloading AstronomicalData for ClassBStar data. A lot faster extracting 2000 names of stars, then DeleteCases to retrieve the associated data. Say 3 minutes X 4 incrementsOf2000. 12 minutes.

Comment: BTW, see my other post: Cool Application That Uses Extracted, Formatted, and Exported Mathematica AstronomicalData. Lots of cool coding techniques.

Comment: It is possible that the download time is limited by latency.  My ping time to Wolfram is 145 ms.

Comment: @Szabolcs - my average ping is 0.3 ms, and it takes me ~9 minutes to run the code above.

Comment: @JasonB 0.3 seconds or 0.3 milliseconds??

Comment: [0.3 ms](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BA1Rz.png) unless I'm reading it wrong.  I think getting a lot of data from the database can take a while, not sure why - I'm no computer scientist.  `EntityValue[
   EntityClass["Chemical", 
    "Organic"], {"MolarMass"}]; ` also seems to take forever